# Upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04.1 from USB preserving existing /home: a question about the right partition to use

Tags: partitioning, usb-installation

Last week my Ubuntu 18.4 installed on a Lenovo laptop failed on a software upgrade and now I'm no longer able to start the GUI, the bootstrap sequence halts and asks me to log on tty.

I mounted an external HD and saved all the important files, now I'm trying to reinstall Focal Fossa preserving the existing /home.

I found several blogs and notes about this procedure and some examples on youtube, i.e. [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sD7Rp8Jt1rE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJF78.png) but I'm still unsure about the right choice.

The installation procedure shows me two existing partition (see first image)

1. /dev/sda1 ext2
2. /dev/sda5 "unknown" and without a type

I tried to change the first partition as ext2 type mount point "/" and the sda5 as ext2 type mount point "home".

I ticked the "Format" checkbox **only on sda1** but when I change sda5 the Format option seems active, the checkbox is greyed and selected.  (see second image)

This means that I cannot keep the existing /home on sda5 ? Can you please help me to find the right choice?
Thank you in advance for your help!

[existing partition on ubuntu 18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJF78.png)
[partition sda5 with format check greyed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Njkn8.png)

Comment: It seems unlikely that sda5 is /home. For one thing, unless you specifically set it up that way, /home is not on a separate partition by default. And it should be an ext type by default  if it had been set up that way.

Comment: This is messed up.  sda1 is the size of an EFI partition and should be formatted Fat32.  sda5 should be mounted as /(root) not /home, unless you have /root on another drive.  If / is on another drive, do not touch /home partition.  Would also recommend using ext4 instead ext2

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!